# How to search string with in between spaces in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to search the string with spaces in between in db2 . The like operator like % % doesn’t work for in between spaces.

Comment: Post (add to your question by using [Edit]) your query as well as some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I don't have a DB2 environment to try it in, but [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_likepredicate.html) states that `%` is a valid wildcard character. Are you using `LIKE` to find the value? For example: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col1 LIKE '% %'`

Answer (score 0):

What are you talking about? Just tried in DB2 and works like a charm:

```
create table title (name varchar(20));

insert into title (name) values ('abc');
insert into title (name) values ('d e');
insert into title (name) values (' fg ');

select * from title where name like '% %';
```

Result:

```
NAME
----
d e
 fg
```

Comment: If name is a char, you example give fg too ;)

Answer (score 0):

If `LIKE` is not sufficient for your needs, you can consider using `REGEXP_LIKE`  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select * from yourtable 
where trim(yourcolumn) like '% %';
```

you can do it too:

```
select * from yourtable 
where LOCATE(' ', yourcolumn)>1 and LOCATE(' ', yourcolumn)<>length(yourcolumn)
```